# RegEx for matching numbers in a string with special patterns

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I try to find a regex that would do the following string matching:

I have DNS Lookups from a Windows DNS Server Debug Log that look like:

```
(4)api3(7)central(6)sophos(3)com(0)
```

For correct parsing in our SIEM Solution I would like to do the following:

omit the first and last (digit) so I get:

```
api3(7)central(6)sophos(3)com
```

and then replace the remaining (digit) with .

If I could only match the (digit) I can replace them with a function in the SIEM Tool.

I played already with some regex but did not find anything that pointed me to a solution. I’m totally new to regex so maybe I’m missing something. I can already replace all (digit) with dots but that was easy.

Answer (score 0):

This expression might satisfy the first condition that you have:

```
(\([0-9]+\))api3(\([0-9]+\))central(\([0-9]+\))sophos(\([0-9]+\))com(\([0-9]+\))
```

You can expand it also and add/reduce the boundary as you wish to maybe something similar to this:

```
(\([0-9]+\))(api3)\([0-9]+\)(central)\([0-9]+\)(sophos)\([0-9]+\)(com)\([0-9]+\)
```

Then replace it with something similar to:

```
$2.$3.$4.$5
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTMiPm/1)

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /(\([0-9]+\))(api3)\([0-9]+\)(central)\([0-9]+\)(sophos)\([0-9]+\)(com)\([0-9]+\)/gm;
const str = `(4)api3(7)central(6)sophos(3)com(0)`;
const subst = `$2.$3.$4.$5`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

You can of-course much simplify it. However, I have added restrictions, just to be safe.

---

#### Edit:

If you want to capture the first and last numbers, you can simply match and replace it with an [expression similar to this](https://regex101.com/r/4UFoHN/1/):

```
(\([0-9]+\))(.+)(\([0-9]+\))
```

Then, you can simply capture the others in the middle with [another expression](https://regex101.com/r/LpwflL/1):

```
 (\([0-9]+\))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comprehensive answer but it was not exactly what I’m was looking for. I have lot of different queries that I have to parse. So, for example her is a list of values that i get:

(9)1932-ms-7(8)8-7cd110(36)9fb432d2-76ce-11e9-52b3-56ca5906e96d(0)
(9)win10-trt(6)msedge(3)net(0)
(9)2012-ms-7(8)8-7cdc2c(36)9631cb56-76ce-11e9-52b3-be39d97995d4(0)
(4)api3(7)central(6)sophos(3)com(0)
(3)121(2)98(3)253(1)8(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)

So the strings have different lengths. I have just to omit the first and last (digit) and capture only the remaining (digit) occurrence.